# Colocar Imagen sobresaliente en Div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap

Estoy intentando colocar una imagen que sobresalga en la parte superior del div padre y siga siendo responsive (estoy usando react-bootstrap), este es un ejemplo de como quiero que se vea:

[image: Ejemplo de expectativa]

Así es como se ve actualmente:

[image: imagen de como se ve]

Este es el codigo del **componente**:

```
   <div className='buyDivColor marX marB px-sm-1 px-md-4 py-sm-4 row'>
  <div className="col-lg-9 buyComing">
    COMING <span className='buySoon'>SOON</span>
  </div>
  <img src={buyCS} alt="prueba" className='col-lg-3 img-fluid'/>
```

**CSS**:

```
.buyDivColor{
  background-color: var(--cNaranja1-color);
  height: auto;
  font-size: 6em;
  line-height: 80px;
 }

.buyComing{
  font-family: "FontExtraBold";
  color: var(--cBlancoTxt-color);
  text-align: start;
}

.buySoon{
  font-family: "FontExtraBold";
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px var(--cBlanco-color);
  color: transparent; 
}
```

Comment: Mejor que con col de bootstrap manejalo con flexbox. Y para que la imagen sea responsive dale con css un width: 100% y height: auto o viceversa

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, no fue mi solución pero me hizo llegar a usar position:absolute en el padre y relative en el hijo, más transform:translate( x, y) para posicionarlo, aun asi gracias.

Comment: @CamiloSW recuerda que puedes contestar tu propia pregunta, saludos